# Restore Google Cloud project

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine, project, state-restoration

i'm unable to restore the pended project for deletion on google cloud.

this projects was shared with me before to manage it from my other account which i forgot the owner id i was use for this project.

i have received the message today from google as per below :

Your Google Cloud Platform project whm-server-195505 was shut down on 2018-09-03T22:21:03+00:00.

If you take no action, after 2018-10-03T22:21:03+00:00, you will be unable to recover this project. If this was unintentional, visit this URL before 2018-10-03T22:21:03+00:00 to cancel the project shutdown:

https://console.developers.google.com/project?pendingDeletion=true&organizationId=793393961037

there is no way to contact google for help except if you have golden plan of support.

how to restore the project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAeNj.png)

image attached

Comment: Not sure whether that's a question for SO... given that I can't even spot the question in the post ;) Either try to contact the current owner or anybody who still has access to the account to cancel the deletion or try to gain access to your "other account" so you can stop the deletion yourself. I doubt that google will stop the deletion just because somebody sends an e-mail or contacts some support as I can't think of mechanism to prove you're a legit owner...

Comment: is there anyway to restore the pended project which will be deleted if i didn't take an action, can i do that by another way, because the interface platform restore option is no working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally the project have been restored as per Google the issue was as per below. but i have restored after google escalation manager contacted me.

----------------------- **Google Response** ---------------------------
Thanks for the reply. I am glad you were able to restore the project.

As mentioned on my previous email, project may misbehave if the the features Shared VPC, IAM Custom Roles, Organization Policy and Folders are used.

---

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Since you forgot the owner account that you used for that project and the interface restore option is not working, then the only way to fix this is with Google Cloud Platform Support help. You can get help from Google Cloud Platform [Technical Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/free_trial_support) if you still have free trial credits, but I believe this is more related to Billing (restore project) so you should be able to get help from Google Cloud Platform [Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) or by following the [steps](https://support.google.com/cloud/troubleshooter/7279311) “My billing account or project is suspended and I need to reopen it.”. They should also be able to give you some *hints* about the owner account that you used for the project (once you explain the situation).

Comment: hi, thanks for replying, i figured the account and it was correct account, i have checked the ( Resources pending deletion ) - and i found my project, when i try to restore it im getting the below error message, with inform i have contacted Google for 50 minutes on the phone and they decided to forward the case to level 2 support.

Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later.

Tracking Number: 6038377607734066100

--------------------

i'm waiting right now the level 2 support.